MPPT Solar Charge Controller Issues
I am working on a solar MPPT circuit to charge a battery from solar energy.

Solar panel: 18V
Battery: LiFePO4 12V, 10Ah

I referred to an MPPT circuit from this post MPPT Solar Charger and changed the MOSFET to AOD240.

Currently, I am using an 18V power source to simulate the solar panel.
I have an issue when I set the IN and #SD pins of the IR2104 to low, there is still voltage from the solar panel charging the battery. Could you help me explain why this is happening?

Why do you use 18 V supply for the IR2104? 12 V would be sufficient, because AOD240 will be fully on above 5 V Vgs? The 1 kohm resistor at the gate of Q1 should go to source of Q1, not to GND. This is critical for the gate driver output.


I have an issue when I set the IN and #SD pins of the IR2104 to low, there is still voltage from the source charging the battery. Could you help me explain why this is happening?

I think by the "voltage from the source", you mean the voltage you measured at \$V_S\$ of IR2104. If that is the case, then there is nothing peculiar about it since there is C6 (100uF), which holds the charge even when both Q1 and Q2 are switched OFF. And it will continue to charge the battery until its voltage goes below one Schottky diode voltage drop above the battery voltage. The voltage will drop to zero eventually, but it will take a while for it to discharge completely.
You can measure the current sourced by the solar panel by reading the voltage on \$V_{IOUT}\$ of the ACS712 when both Q1 and Q2 are switched OFF. If the reading is close to 2.5V, it indicates that no current is flowing, and therefore, no battery charging is taking place.

Sorry for the confusion. I mean that there is still voltage from solar panel charging the battery

How did you come to the conclusion that the solar panel was still charging the battery when both Q1 and Q2 were switched OFF? Can you explain the method you used to measure the "charging"?

What is the reading on VIOUT of ACS712? Is it close to 2.5V when both Q1 and Q2 are switched OFF?
